# Laravel 8: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8, and I make a simple form which goes like this:

```
<form action="/create" method="POST">
    @csrf 
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title"></br>
    <label for="body">Body:</label>
    <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Then on `web.php`, I put this:

```
Route::post('/create',function(){
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    Article::create([
        'title' => request('title'),
        'body' => request('body')
    ]);
    return redirect('/create');
});
```

But as soon as I submit the form, I see the message:

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, 2020-10-27 07:36:47, 2020-10-27 07:36:47))**

And I know it means that there is a column at table that cannot be *NULL*. But as you can see in the code, I determine the validation, so if the inputs are not filled, the *Required* message should be pop up, but it does not and again, error message appears.

And this is also the migration of table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

So if you know, how can I solve this problem, please let me know, I would really appreciate that...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `dd(request()->all())` to see all the post params are present

Comment: `array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "WupvBPXbBaL1lxOrOMRSq5weZH654tKNh2ewwJZS"
  "title" => null
  "body" => null
]`

Comment: So, that's why your code is not working. My recommendations; 1) Try not using Closure-based request handlers. Use controllers.

Comment: So why the validation does not work, so the user MUST fill the form

Comment: 2) Use `$request->validate()` instead of making new validator.

Comment: did you set fillable in article model? you must set it

Comment: @ruwroveajaic Can you share your Model code? Seems like you have not set title in fillable

Comment: @ruwroveajaic You are creating a validation but not validating the request. Read the documentation on Manually Creating validators https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Validator instance manually you have to handle the failed validation yourself. You can check if the validation fails with `$validator->fails()`. I would use `$request->validate()` instead, so Laravel handles the failed validation automatically.

[Manually Creating Validators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators):

> If you do not want to use the `validate` method on the request, you may
> create a validator instance manually using the `Validator` [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades). The
> `make` method on the facade generates a new validator instance:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the blog post...
    }
}
```

> After checking if the request validation failed, you may use the
> `withErrors` method to flash the error messages to the session. When
> using this method, the `$errors` variable will automatically be shared
> with your views after redirection, allowing you to easily display them
> back to the user. The `withErrors` method accepts a validator, a
> `MessageBag`, or a PHP `array`.

[$request->validate()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    // The blog post is valid...
}
```

> Now we are ready to fill in our `store` method with the logic to
> `validate` the new blog post. To do this, we will use the validate
> method provided by the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object. If the
> validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally;
> however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the
> proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user. In
> the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be
> generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.

So in your case it would be the following:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Article;

Route::post('/create', function (Request $request) {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    Article::create($validatedData);

    return redirect('/create');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a Validator instance but not validating the data using it.

```
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    // Validates request data. If fails redirect to /create
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
     }
    // Validation passed, create article.
    Article::create([
        'title' => request()->input('title'),
        'body' => request()->input('body')
    ]);
    return redirect('/create');
```

Also [read about working with validation error messages](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#working-with-error-messages) to understand how to display error messages on the `/create` page.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

You can see this in a trait the model uses:

```php
trait GuardsAttributes
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['*'];

    // ...
}
```

So you need to make the fields fillable.

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::post('/create',function(){
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    Article::create([
        'title' => request()->input('title'),
        'body' => request()->input('body')
    ]);
    return redirect('/create');
});
```

Comment: Did you write the fillable feature in the Article file?

Comment: protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body'
    ];

Comment: Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
])->validate();

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Route::post('/create',function(){
$validateData = request()->validate([
'title' => 'required',
'body' => 'required',
]);
Article::create(request()->all());
return redirect('/create');
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it